# Boost::graph getting the path up to the root

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-graph

I have the following graph

```
boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, GraphItem>;
```

and i need to get the path up to the parent all the way to the root node.
I cannot change the type of the graph, is there any algorithm for this and what complexity does it have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you know your graph to actually be a tree you can use the topological sort to find the root.

> *If you only know it to be a DAG, you should probably find roots by finding leaf nodes in the reverse graph - that's a  bit more expensive. But maybe you just know the roots before-hand, so I'll consider this problem solved for this demo.*

I'll start with your graph:

```
struct GraphItem { std::string name; };

using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, GraphItem>;
```

The name is convenient for demo purposes. You can have whatever you need in that bundle. Let's add some readable typedefs:

```
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Order  = std::vector<Vertex>;
using Path   = std::deque<Vertex>;
static constexpr Vertex NIL = -1;
```

To find that root, you'd write:

```
Vertex find_root(Graph const& g) { // assuming there's only 1
    Order order;
    topological_sort(g, back_inserter(order));

    return order.back();
}
```

To get all shortest paths from a given root you only need a BFS (which is equivalent to Dijkstra's if your edge weights are all equivalent):

```
Order shortest_paths(Vertex root, Graph const& g) {
    // find shortest paths from the root
    Order predecessors(num_vertices(g), NIL);
    auto recorder = boost::record_predecessors(predecessors.data(), boost::on_examine_edge());

    boost::breadth_first_search(g, root, boost::visitor(boost::make_bfs_visitor(recorder)));

    // assert(boost::count(predecessors, NIL) == 1); // if only one root allowed
    assert(predecessors[root] == NIL);

    return predecessors;
}
```

Given the order returned by the BFS, you can find the paths you are looking for:

```
Path path(Vertex target, Order const& predecessors) {
    Path path { target };

    for (auto pred = predecessors[target]; pred != NIL; pred = predecessors[pred]) {
        path.push_back(pred);
    }

    return path;
}
```

You could print those given a suitable property-map to get a display-name:

```
template <typename Name> void print(Path path, Name name_map) {
    while (!path.empty()) {
        std::cout << name_map[path.front()];
        path.pop_front();
        if (!path.empty()) std::cout << " <- ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

## Demo Graph

Let's start a demo

```
int main() {
    Graph g;
    // name helpers
    auto names   = get(&GraphItem::name, g);
```

That's a good demonstration of using a property-map to get names from vertices. Let's define some helpers, so you can find e.g. node `by_name("E")`:

```
    auto named   = [=]   (std::string target) { return [=](Vertex vd) { return names[vd] == target; }; };
    auto by_name = [=,&g](std::string target) { return *boost::find_if(vertices(g), named(target)); };
```

Let's fill the graph `g` with sample data:

```
    // read sample graph
    {
        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("node_id", names);
        read_graphviz(R"( digraph {
                A -> H;
                B -> D; B -> F; C -> D; C -> G;
                E -> F; E -> G; G -> H;
                root -> A; root -> B
            })", g, dp);
    }
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

> Note that this particular graph has multiple roots. The one returned by `find_root` happens to be the furthest one because it's found last.

Now to find some nodes from given roots:

```
    for (auto root : { find_root(g), by_name("E") }) {
        auto const order = shortest_paths(root, g);
        std::cout << " -- From " << names[root] << "\n";

        for (auto target : { "G", "D", "H" })
            print(path(by_name(target), order), names);
    }
```

Which prints

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dda77515b9e4204d)**

```
 -- From root
G
D <- B <- root
H <- A <- root
 -- From E
G <- E
D
H <- G <- E
```

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dda77515b9e4204d)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>       // adjacency_list
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>     // find_if
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp> // shortest paths
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp> // range find_if
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>  // read_graphviz
#include <iostream>

struct GraphItem { std::string name; };

using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, GraphItem>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Order  = std::vector<Vertex>;
using Path   = std::deque<Vertex>;
static constexpr Vertex NIL = -1;

Vertex find_root(Graph const& g);
Order  shortest_paths(Vertex root, Graph const& g);
Path   path(Vertex target, Order const& predecessors);
template <typename Name> void print(Path path, Name name_map);

int main() {
    Graph g;
    // name helpers
    auto names   = get(&GraphItem::name, g);
    auto named   = [=]   (std::string target) { return [=](Vertex vd) { return names[vd] == target; }; };
    auto by_name = [=,&g](std::string target) { return *boost::find_if(vertices(g), named(target)); };

    // read sample graph
    {
        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("node_id", names);
        read_graphviz(R"( digraph {
                A -> H;
                B -> D; B -> F; C -> D; C -> G;
                E -> F; E -> G; G -> H;
                root -> A; root -> B
            })", g, dp);
    }

    // 3 paths from 2 different roots
    for (auto root : { find_root(g), by_name("E") }) {
        auto const order = shortest_paths(root, g);
        std::cout << " -- From " << names[root] << "\n";

        for (auto target : { "G", "D", "H" })
            print(path(by_name(target), order), names);
    }
}

Vertex find_root(Graph const& g) { // assuming there's only 1
    Order order;
    topological_sort(g, back_inserter(order));

    return order.back();
}

Order shortest_paths(Vertex root, Graph const& g) {
    // find shortest paths from the root
    Order predecessors(num_vertices(g), NIL);
    auto recorder = boost::record_predecessors(predecessors.data(), boost::on_examine_edge());

    boost::breadth_first_search(g, root, boost::visitor(boost::make_bfs_visitor(recorder)));

    // assert(boost::count(predecessors, NIL) == 1); // if only one root allowed
    assert(predecessors[root] == NIL);

    return predecessors;
}

Path path(Vertex target, Order const& predecessors) {
    Path path { target };

    for (auto pred = predecessors[target]; pred != NIL; pred = predecessors[pred]) {
        path.push_back(pred);
    }

    return path;
}

template <typename Name>
void print(Path path, Name name_map) {
    while (!path.empty()) {
        std::cout << name_map[path.front()];
        path.pop_front();
        if (!path.empty()) std::cout << " <- ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it slipped my mind to Thank you for a great explanation on how to solve this.

Comment: @sehe hi! I'm having trouble understanding this `find_root` example. E.g., you said that "this particular graph has multiple roots. The one returned by find_root happens to be the furthest one because it's found last", but to me it seems that since it's directed, only 'root' node can access the whole set of vertices ?

Comment: @WaterFox A "root" is any node with zero in-degree. In the example diagram you can [see that `E`, `C` and `root` are roots in that sense](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4457f7dcc9013312). My comment indicates that "find_root" doesn't necessarily find a specific root, it accidentally returns the last one. Because `E` and `C` have no in-edges, they're inevitably outside any other tree in this forest, which means that your suggestion that `root` is a spanning tree for the entire set of vertices cannot be correct?

Comment: @sehe I see, with the zero in-degree definition it makes much more sense :) Thank you :)